# Why is this set function unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let
$$\mu(A)=a \,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\,A=(-\infty,a] $$
$$\mu(A)=b-a \,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\,A=(a,b] $$
$$\mu(A)=-b \,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\,A=(b,\infty) $$
$$\mu(A)=0 \,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\,A=\mathbb R $$

This is an example given to us as an example of a finite but unbounded set function.

I know why it is finite but why is it unbounded?

Comment: $\mu ((-\infty, n])=n \to \infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, doesn't this also mean it is not finite?

Comment: No there is  no set $A$ for which $\mu (A)=\infty$ or $\mu (A)=-\infty$